# QMessageBox change text of standard button

Tags: python, pyqt, qmessagebox

I want to use `QMessageBox.Question` for the icon. But i want to change the text of standard buttons. I do not want the text of buttons to be the "Yes" and "No". I want them to be "Evet" and "Iptal". Here my codes.

```
choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Kaydet!',
                                    'Kaydetmek İstediğinize Emin Misiniz?',
                                    QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
```

Comment: Actually, now i overcome this problem like this                                       choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, "Kaydet!", "Kaydetmek İstediğinize Emin Misiniz?", "Evet",  button1Text='İptal',   defaultButtonNumber=0,  escapeButtonNumber=-1)
        if choice == 0:
            self.frame_11.show()
        else:
            pass

Comment: That form of QMesageBox::question is both undocumented and commented as obsolete. Still exits as of Qt 5.15.4 but no Guarantee of this even for the next bug fix release much less Qt6 which is now released.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Qt provides translations for all the built-in strings it uses in its libraries. You just need to install a translator for the current locale:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
locale = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
path = QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)
translator.load('qt_%s' % locale, path)
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

Comment: You might also want to check other files than 'qt_%s'. For example my Qt installation had empty qt_pl.qm, which failed to load, but qtbase_pl.qm had all translations I wanted. There are other types of translation files in `TranslationsPath` directory as well.

Answer (score 39):

To do so you need to create an instance of a `QMessageBox` and manually change the text of the buttons:

```
box = QtGui.QMessageBox()
box.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Question)
box.setWindowTitle('Kaydet!')
box.setText('Kaydetmek İstediğinize Emin Misiniz?')
box.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes|QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
buttonY = box.button(QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes)
buttonY.setText('Evet')
buttonN = box.button(QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
buttonN.setText('Iptal')
box.exec_()

if box.clickedButton() == buttonY:
    # YES pressed
elif box.clickedButton() == buttonN:
    # NO pressed
```

Comment: Thank you Daniele, appreciate it

Comment: 'no' in QtGui.QMessageBox.no should be capitaized -> QtGui.QMessageBox.No; I cannot edit just one letter, sorry.

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks!

Comment: Just to complete your customization: `box.setDefaultButton(QtGui.QMessageBox.No)` (or `QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes`, your call)

Comment: The No role condition does not work. If I have to perform a deleteFeature function if the user clicks on the no option.. how to go about it?